# Rigify To Unity weird bend

Tags: unity, rigify

[image]

Hi guys,
I tried the Rigify to Unity add-on and the hand started to bend in a weird way like this.
I checked all the weights and it seems correct. Do you know what's going on here? Is it a IK issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you add a minimal blend file so it can be looked at?

Comment: how to add blend file here?

Comment: You can't upload it directly to this site, but you can provide a url to any provider you choose: Google Drive, Dropbox, wherever.

Comment: A Blend file would be nice. However, this looks like the normals on your mesh are inverted. Unparent the character from the rig, go to edit mode, select all geometry, and press shift+N. The parent the rig again.